# Get status of all objects of model

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Room(models.Model):
    # Default all rooms are Free
    number = models.ForeignKey(RoomNumber)

class Reserved(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(Visitor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    room = models.OneToOneField(Room)
    reserved_date = models.DateTimeField()
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

How to get status of all Rooms in a List. 
In status of all rooms are in :

1. Reserved
2. Free Rooms
3. Busy Rooms

I myself tried to do this:

ListView

```
reserved = Reserved.objects\
    .filter(room=OuterRef('pk'))\
    .filter(begin_date=timezone.now())\
    .values(count=Count('pk'))

Room.objects.annotate(reserved=Subquery(reserved[:1]))
```

but no result :(
And how to get in template status of rooms?
Through if else condition?

Thanks you all in advance

Comment: You don't give us enough information in my opinion. But if you want an opinion as to how to make your list, make a function that will iterate through all your rooms, and return something that will suit you : a list composed of 3 lists according to the status, a dict of all rooms...

Comment: ask me what you can not understand

Comment: I understood your problem, but we don't have a proper code to test your program. I gave you some hints in my comment above though

Answer (score 0):

I've worked a little bit on your problem and it a little bit complicated.

**First of all**:

You should use `models.ForeignKey(Room)` instead of `OneToOneField(Room)`:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

`OneToOneField` means that each 'Room' instance can have only one reservation in system, but in reality it can have many (planned in future). Also I don't think there is a need to put room number as a separate model, that's why I rewrote it to simple charfield that accepts 3 characters.

**Second of all**:

You need to build ***validation*** for ***reservation form*** that will prevent people from reserving room in the time when someone has already reserved it (I had no time to write it right now, but you can use queryset from below to write it by yourself. I will try to do it later)

**And most important thing**:

My solution is based on simple idea:

*"If you can find which rooms are reserved for selected day, you know which rooms are free"*

And it's quite easy to check which rooms are busy:

begin_date <= **my_date** <= end_date

So thats why I've build just model Manager which return rooms that are reserved for given date.

```
from django.db.models import Q
import datetime


class ReservedManager(models.Manager):
    def ondate(self, my_date):
        query = Reservation.instances.filter(
            Q(begin_date__lte=my_date),
            Q(end_date__gte=my_date)
            )
        return query

# Create your models here.
class Room(models.Model):
    # Default all rooms are Free
    number = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.number))



class Reservation(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    reserved_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    begin_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    instances = models.Manager()
    reserved = ReservedManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.room)+' from '+str(self.begin_date)+' to '+str(self.end_date))
```

And you can easily acces information:

```
choosen_date = datetime.date(2017, 12, 23)
queryset = Reservation.reserved.ondate(choosen_date)
```

And at this point you can access Room of reservation instance however you like:

```
queryset[1].room
```